# Space time analysis. Finding spatial patterns (cluster&disperse) over time in point data sets

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, point, time, events

I am trying to describe/find statistically spatial patterns in a point data set of industrial sites. The points feature apart from

1. their location,
2. a date for their opening,
3. a date for their closure and
4. the length of operation, but no other value.

I would like to see at which moment in time certain patterns emerge and disappear, such as sudden dense cluster or dispersal. I investigated the data set 'manually' and found several moments in time, which show the kind of patterns I am looking for (see image 1). I would however like to explore and describe these statistically, also most likely there are relations through out time, which I wouldn't find else wise.

[image: Locations of Industry over time, size of dot indicates length of operation (the bigger the dot, the longer the period)]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJe7L.jpg)

I am currently working with ArcMap 10.2.2 and have explored some possibilities of space-time analysis. I tried several methods, such as Average Nearest Neighbour, Grouping or Multi-Distance Spatial Cluster Analysis (Ripleys K Function), the difficulty is that these method do not incorporate the time dimension. The best I could find is as described here (http://video.esri.com/watch/1681/spatial-pattern-analysis-mapping-trends-and-clusters) a time space analysis using a Spatial Weight Matrix (Although here I have to introduce a bias in the length of relation [how long and how far away events should be so that the analysis considers them as related]), in combination with a HotSpot analysis, followed by 3 dimensional representation.

The problem I have with this is, that my data set doesn't feature a value or magnitude field against which I could apply a HotSpots analysis. The only values I have are Dates, or respectively time length, which I can not apply a hot spot analysis on.

[image: Plot of all industrial locations using the Z axis for the date of closure]

Does anyone of you maybe has a good idea to analyse such a point data set?

Comment: For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.